# When using FFTW in Julia can I link to a locally-compiled version of FFTW?

Tags: performance, julia, fftw

When I install `Pkg.add("FFTW")`, how does Julia link to FFTW? I guess it downloads a pre-compiled version because I didn't give it a path to link my local version and it didn't seem to take long enough to be compiling FFTW from source. Is that correct? If so, is there a way to set Julia to use a locally compiled and optimized version of FFTW? I ask because I have a simulation code with both a Julia and a C++ version, and the C++ one runs about 6-7x faster, even though I think both should be spending most of their time in FFTW calls. So I am wondering if the difference is that the Julia version is using a less well optimized build of FFTW.

Comment: Using giordano's answer below I was able to link my Julia and C++ versions to the exact same FFTW library, and the performance difference was still the same 6-7x. Still a mystery to me where the speed difference is coming from, but it might be differences in the implementation in the two codes (of which there are some not insignificant ones). That's beyond the scope of this question though!

Comment: Are you saying the two code are basically the same?  Note that C++ and Julia have different memory layouts (Julia is column-major, C++ row-major: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-column-major).  If you need to access multi-dimensional arrays this makes quite a lot of difference.  I'd ask for help on discourse: https://discourse.julialang.org/

Comment: Unfortunately not totally the same. The C++ was written as a rough benchmark, but only for a simplified case - we probably expect the Julia to be at least 2x slower because it has to do more work. I've been looking through https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/ and found a few things to speed up in our Julia code already. We need to decide now if it's worth putting the work in to do a better benchmark, or if we're happy enough already that Julia is in the ballpark in terms of performance. We're not super worried about optimization yet, I was just checking for easy gains!

Comment: That's a common pattern: when you're a newcomer to Julia you hit some performance pitfalls (globals, memory layout, type-instability, excessive allocations, etc...), but once you get more experience you can incrementally fix the errors and get performance which is very close to C/C++. Even if performance isn't usually better than those languages, the easier development pays off. However I recommend again asking for help on discourse for the remaining optimisations, if you're interested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many Julia packages provide prebuilt libraries through the so called [JLL](https://juliapackaging.github.io/BinaryBuilder.jl/dev/jll/#Non-dev%27ed-JLL-packages).  Julia also provides [a mechanism to override these artifacts](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/artifacts/#Overriding-artifact-locations-1).

In particular, your `~/.julia/artifacts/Overrides.toml` will look like

```
[f5851436-0d7a-5f13-b9de-f02708fd171a]
FFTW = "...."
```

where `....` is the "prefix" where your FFTW is installed, i.e. the directory in which there is the `lib/libfftw....` file.  You can read more about overriding artifacts of JLL packages at [https://juliapackaging.github.io/BinaryBuilder.jl/dev/jll/#Non-dev'ed-JLL-packages](https://juliapackaging.github.io/BinaryBuilder.jl/dev/jll/#Non-dev%27ed-JLL-packages)

If you happen to find that the slowdown is due to the different library, please do report it to https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/Yggdrasil/

Comment: Thanks, this is going in the direction I want. I'm having trouble because it seems the Julia FFTW package is using libfftw-3.3.9 (`using FFTW; FFTW.version`), but I've installed the latest release libfftw-3.3.8 and apparently the two aren't compatible. I guess I need to try compiling from the FFTW Github repo, but that's apparently not straightforward (big warnings in all-caps in the readme), so I need to read the manual. Will try tomorrow.

Comment: My linking problem was because of the flags that I used to compile FFTW. It seems using `--enable-threads --with-combined-threads` and not using `--enable-openmp` is required when configuring FFTW. For anyone else seeing this, it is also necessary to configure/make/make install both with and without the `--enable-float` option to have both single- and double-precision versions of libfftw available.

Comment: I also found that in `~/.julia/artifacts/Overrides.toml`
```
f5851436-0d7a-5f13-b9de-f02708fd171a = "...."
```
worked, while the form suggested in the answer did not.